# createAsyncThunk isn't changing state

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So, i'am trying to create async thunk action, to mock data from file to the state.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import mocktasks from './mocktasks';

export interface TasksState {
  data: Task[];
}

const initialState: TasksState = {
  data: [],
};

export const fetchTasks = createAsyncThunk('tasks/fetchTasks', () => mocktasks);

export const tasksSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tasks',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTasks: (state:TasksState, action: PayloadAction<Task[]>) => ({
      ...state,
      data: action.payload,
    }),
    addTask: (state: TasksState, action: PayloadAction<Task>) => ({
      ...state,
      data: [...state.data, action.payload],
    }),
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchTasks.fulfilled.name]: (state, action: PayloadAction<Task[]>) => ({
      ...state,
      data: action.payload,
    }),
  },
});

export const { setTasks, addTask } = tasksSlice.actions;

export default tasksSlice.reducer;
```

But there is a strange thing: even though, fetch actions have dispatched, my state hasn't changed.
[State and dispatched actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSuxp.png)

I thought, that there was an issue with passing the payload to fetchTasks/fulfilled, but Redux devtools shows, that fulfilled has right data in payload, that is obtained from mock file:[Action payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NxA5.png)

UPD: even though, using dispatch(setTasks(mocktasks)) inside createAsyncThunk works just like i need.

Comment: Have you tried `[fetchTasks.fulfilled]: ...` (without `.name`) in `extraReducers`? This is what the official docs are showing in their examples.

Comment: @timotgl Yeah, i've tried, but TS is complaining about computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `builder` notation to avoid typescript errors ([official recomendation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-map-object-notation) from redux-toolkit docs):

```js
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    .addCase(fetchTasks.fulfilled, (state) => ({
      ...state,
      data: action.payload,
    }))
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

`[fetchTasks.fulfilled.type]` should work, as `.name` seems to always return the string `actionCreator`.